# How to set a ComboBox Item to match a cell in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combo box that is set up as a DropDownList.
I am wanting to select the corresponding item from the box that matches a selected Cell in a Row of a DataGridView.
Ideally, upon clicking the Edit Button, the report type DropDown would select monthly to match the TimeSpan Column in the highlighted row.
I am trying to loop through the list testing if the strings match and setting the index value if true.  I set up a message box to confirm that both strings match, however it is not changing the index position.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeBtnVisibility();
    btnEdit.Enabled = false;
    tbReportInput.Focus();

    int selectedrowIndex = reportsDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
    tbReportInput.Text = reportsDataGridView.Rows[selectedrowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < cbSpan.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("INDEX \n" + cbSpan.Items[i] + "\n\nDGV \n" + reportsDataGridView.Rows[selectedrowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
        if (cbSpan.GetItemText(cbSpan.Items[i]) == reportsDataGridView.Rows[selectedrowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString())
        {
            cbSpan.SelectedIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

When I  run the code with a message box to test the values I'm showing that both are the same, however, my If is not triggering.

[image]

Comment: This can be done in 0 lines of code if you bind the data

Comment: When binding the data, I have an issue where my data view timespan column is changing to whatever value is selected in the dropbox.

Comment: It's a two way street..

Comment: Is there a way to bind the data and to make it a one-way street unless otherwise told?

Comment: Er... Yes. You make the combobox a label. There is no point using a combobox if you're going to make it one way in the way you describe.. If you're going to have it be "sometimes editable, sometimes not", make the combo Enabled=false, or hide/show it in exchange for another control, like a readonly textbox (allows copy paste)

Comment: The reason I used a combo box, to begin with, is for when I'm writing a new "report" to the database.  The user can select what kind of report it is and save it to the database.  The issue I'm having is when a user wants to edit that report.  Upon clicking edit I want the same report type to be selected to avoid having to change it every time unless it needs to be changed.  So I need it to be editable both times but at the same time, I don't it to changeable unless the edit button has been clicked.

Comment: I don't think any of that means I need to change my answer- other than now knowing you're working with database you life will get even easier if you open the DataSet designer, right click and choose new TableAdapter; connect it to the db and it will use the db schema to generate the table for you, so even less typing code (0 lines if you have a table that lists your timespans)

Answer (score 0):

For demo purposes, make a new project so you don't disturb your existing code, then do this:

- add a DataSet type of file to your project, and in the properties grid, call it reporting
- Open it, right click and add a datatable, call it Reports
- Right click the table and add an Id column. Set it's type to be int32. Add timespan and reportdata columns (default string), and add a TimeStamp column of type datetime
- Add another datatable, call it TimeSpans, and have a Disp and Val column, both strings
- Save the set
- Switch to the form designer
- Show the Data Sources window, on the view menu, other windows
- Expand the data sources window tree as much as you can.
- Drag the Reports node onto the form, a data grid appears
- Drag the TimeSpans node onto the form, but then delete the grid and the binding navigator it makes leaving only the bindingsource
- Change the timespan node under the reports node to be a combo, and drag it to the form. Drag the reportdata TextBox node to the form
- Click the timespan combo, set its data source to be the timespansbindingsource, set the displaymember and valuemember properties to Disp and Val. Set the drop down style to dropdownlist
- Switch to code view and add some lines for the timespan entries:

```
    reportingDataSet.TimeSpans.AddTimeSpansRow("Daily","Daily");
    reportingDataSet.TimeSpans.AddTimeSpansRow("Monthly","Monthly");
```

And so on..

I know I said it was 0 lines, but you need data from somewhere ;) and the 0 lines comment was in reference to connecting the DGV and the cobo; that part has already been done during the above

That's it, just run the app

Answer (score 0):

After running the debugger again I noticed that the TimeSpan cell had a lot of white space behind the value.  Trimmed the whitespace off and all is good now.

Comment: You've probably used a CHAR data type